# Charts In Lightning Component Framework

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Are there any free charting libraries which can be used to display charts(Gauge/Bar) in lightning component framework?

Note: The fusion chart has good UI but it is paid for commercial usage. Are there any other library compatible with Lightning Framework.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start is with the "non- exhaustive list of libraries that are known to work with LockerService" that are part of the page [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html). That includes [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

(Charts in D3 are usually done with a library that sits on top of D3, as otherwise you are having to construct the charts from low level elements like lines.)

Comment: I have one doubt. There is non- exhaustive list of libraries to be used in lightning component. Can we use any other libraries like fusionChart.js or blockUI.js etc. If yes, How to check if a particular library is compatible with lightning locker service or not?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria I don't know of a defined process - might be a good new question to post on this site.

Comment: Thank You @keith. I posted new question. Let me know if you find how to implement fusionchart in lightning component.

Answer (score 3):

We're using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) Version 5.0.7 in our application using Lightning Framework.

It is strict mode compatible and it works even when Locker Service is active. Also, it has lots of options and is highly customizable.

You can checkout [Highcharts Demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) to know the various types of charts available.

Note: It's free for non-commercial use(ie. for a personal website, a school site or a non-profit organisation).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [D3](https://d3js.org) charts. They have probably the most extensive library of charts and above all it is FREE!

It is also locker service compatible, I have tried latest version of d3 working fine with locker service enabled.

Other free yet popular charting options:

1. [Open charts](http://www.chartjs.org/) - Haven't tried it in Lightning.
2. [C3 Charts](http://c3js.org/) - Based D3 charts - Never tried it.